# How to realize hot update in cordova code

Tags: cordova-plugins

there
Are there any plugins realizing hot updates in Cordova? I tried [cordova-hot-code-push-plugin](https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-hot-code-push) and [cordova-plugin-code-push](https://github.com/microsoft/cordova-plugin-code-push), but they are achieved, and I meet error that can't hot update.

thanks for any suggestions.

---